# How can I add values to a NewtonSoft JObect?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am usin NewtonSoft JSON.Net and I have a JObject that I need to add and remove items to and form it dynamicly from my code.
If this is my json:

```
{
"IgnoredInterests": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "test"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "test"
    }
]
}
```

I need to be able to add more items or even remove items from it via code.
How can I add this to the JObject:

```
{
   "Id": 3,
   "Name": "test"
}
```

And even remove:

```
{
   "Id": 2,
   "Name": "test"
}
```

I appreciate your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string json = @"{
                'IgnoredInterests': [
                    {
                        'Id': 1,
                        'Name': 'test'
                    },
                    {
                        'Id': 2,
                        'Name': 'test'
                    }
                ]
                }";
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

        string json_add = @"{
                   'Id': 3,
                   'Name': 'test'
                }";    

        JArray array = obj.GetValue("IgnoredInterests") as JArray;

        JObject obj_add = JObject.Parse(json_add);

        array.Add(obj_add);


        foreach (JObject item in array.Children())
        {
            if (item.GetValue("Id").ToString() == "2")
            {
                array.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I thougt about this solution also:
**`string a = json.ToString();
a = a.Insert(a.Length - 4, ",{ \"Id\": 3, \"Name\": \"test\" }");
json = JObject.Parse(a);`**

What do you think could have better performance ?

Comment: Of course the raw "Insert" solution has better performance, but this means that you have to know where to insert. You can choose the best solution according to your needs and preferences.

Comment: I always put it at the end as the last item so I think I'll stick to performance, but I will also keep your solution. Thanks (-:

Comment: How can I use your solution to add multiple items ?

Comment: You can add one by one, more information about Newtonsoft.net [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)